# UILabel как сделать внутренние отступы

Tags: swift, uikit

Как сделать у UILabel, как на картинке ниже? Сейчас пробую делать так, но не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Hello World"
        label.backgroundColor = .black
        label.textColor = .white
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true
        label.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
        label.bounds.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 50, left: 50, bottom: 50, right: 50))

        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476646/uilabel-text-margin

Comment: Этот вариант не работает